# Jquery Count number of occurances in array

Tags: jquery

I'd like to count the number of each element in my array

Example:

```
 var basketItems = ['1','3','1','4','4'];

 jQuery.each(basketItems, function(key,value) {

 // Go through each element and tell me how many times it occurs, output this and remove duplicates

 }
```

I'd then like to output

```
Item  |  Occurances
--------------------
1     |  2
3     |  1
4     |  2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try with:

```
var basketItems = ['1','3','1','4','4'],
    counts = {};

jQuery.each(basketItems, function(key,value) {
  if (!counts.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
    counts[value] = 1;
  } else {
    counts[value]++;
  }
});
```

Result:

```
Object {1: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var basketItems = ['1','3','1','4','4'];
var returnObj = {};

$.each(basketItems, function(key,value) {

var numOccr = $.grep(basketItems, function (elem) {
    return elem === value;
}).length;
    returnObj[value] = numOccr
});
console.log(returnObj);
```

**output:**

```
Object { 1=2, 3=1, 4=2}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6gT6B/1/)