# How can I count the occurrence of a value of an attribute in an array of anonymous objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm hoping to find an efficient answer as as in the second answer (Rajesh Dhiman) in [Jquery Count number of occurances in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557502/jquery-count-number-of-occurances-in-array)

Javascript of JQuery are both acceptable.

Consider:

```
var items = new Array();
items.push({x: 1, y: "what"});
items.push({x: 3, y: "ever"});
items.push({x: 4, y: "can"});
items.push({x: 4, y: "happen"});
items.push({x: 1, y: "will"});
items.push({x: 4, y: "happen"});
```

Seeking results like (sorted or not doesn't matter):

```
res = {1:2, 3:1, 4:3}
```

All other related answers on here that I can find only consider counting simplistic arrays or not JS/JQ.

Comment: Just had this thought.  What if I wanted result in an array of anonymous objects such as `result = ({x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 3, y: 1}, {x: 4, y: 3})` ?  @Nenad Vracar @NinaScholz

Comment: for now I'm just reprossessing `result` as `var res = new Array();
 Object.getOwnPropertyNames(result).forEach(function(val, idx, array) {
  res.push({x: val, cnt: result[val]});
 });
 console.log(res);`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and return object as result.

```js
var items = new Array();
items.push({x: 1, y: "what"});
items.push({x: 3, y: "ever"});
items.push({x: 4, y: "can"});
items.push({x: 4, y: "happen"});
items.push({x: 1, y: "will"});
items.push({x: 4, y: "happen"});

var result = items.reduce(function(r, o) {
  r[o.x] = (r[o.x] || 0) + 1;
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Just had this thought. What if I wanted result in an array of anonymous objects such as `result = ({x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 3, y: 1}, {x: 4, y: 3})` ?

Comment: for now I'm just reprossessing `result` as `var res = new Array(); Object.getOwnPropertyNames(result).forEach(function(val, idx, array) { res.push({x: val, cnt: result[val]}); }); console.log(res);`

Answer (score 2):

No need for [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), an [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) works well.

The result is an object. the reference does not change, so it is not necessary to use something which change the reference to a result.

If, for examle, a result is made of a countinuous addition, then the result would change, but here, with an object, it does not change. It is more some kind of laziness, to move an object through the reduce.

```js
var items = [{ x: 1, y: "what" }, { x: 3, y: "ever" }, { x: 4, y: "can" }, { x: 4, y: "happen" }, { x: 1, y: "will" }, { x: 4, y: "happen" }],
    count = Object.create(null);

items.forEach(function(a) {
    count[a.x] = (count[a.x] || 0) + 1;
});

console.log(count);
```

As requested with an array of objects for the count. this proposal uses the `this` object hashing the included items in the result set.

```js
var items = [{ x: 1, y: "what" }, { x: 3, y: "ever" }, { x: 4, y: "can" }, { x: 4, y: "happen" }, { x: 1, y: "will" }, { x: 4, y: "happen" }],
    result = [];

items.forEach(function(a) {
    if (!this[a.x]) {
        this[a.x] = { x: a.x, cnt: 0 };
        result.push(this[a.x]);
    }
    this[a.x].cnt++;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

With [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), a hash table as closure and an array.

```js
var items = [{ x: 1, y: "what" }, { x: 3, y: "ever" }, { x: 4, y: "can" }, { x: 4, y: "happen" }, { x: 1, y: "will" }, { x: 4, y: "happen" }],
    result = items.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function(r, a) {
            if (!hash[a.x]) {
                hash[a.x] = { x: a.x, cnt: 0 };
                r.push(hash[a.x]);
            }
            hash[a.x].cnt++;
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What would be a contrary remark for the use of reduce?

Comment: Same number of lines. Would just be a readability preference at this point. How would the performances compare?

Comment: I guess performance wise I should add that the array will only have at max maybe 70 objects.  Typical around 35 ~40.  In other words very small.

Comment: it's not a matter of speed, just some kind of programming style.

Comment: Just had this thought. What if I wanted result in an array of anonymous objects such as `result = ({x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 3, y: 1}, {x: 4, y: 3})` ?

Comment: @ninascholz for now I'm just reprossessing `result` as `var res = new Array(); Object.getOwnPropertyNames(result).forEach(function(val, idx, array) { res.push({x: val, cnt: result[val]}); }); console.log(res);`

Comment: Can't do that with reduce() can you :-)

Comment: reduce has not this object, bit if you really want, the you could use a closure and reduce (but i do not recommend it).

Answer (score 0):

A quick and sorted solution :

```
var items = new Array();
items.push({x: 1, y: "what"});
items.push({x: 3, y: "ever"});
items.push({x: 4, y: "can"});
items.push({x: 4, y: "happen"});
items.push({x: 1, y: "will"});
items.push({x: 4, y: "happen"});
var res = items.map(x => ({x: x.x})).sort((a,b) => a.x - b.x).reduce((r,o) => {
    r[o.x] = (r[o.x] || 0) + 1;
    return r;
}, {});
console.log(res); //{ '1': 2, '3': 1, '4': 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to iterate over it and finding the occurrences. below is the code and the demo.

```js
var items = new Array();
items.push({x: 1, y: "what"});
items.push({x: 3, y: "ever"});
items.push({x: 4, y: "can"});
items.push({x: 4, y: "happen"});
items.push({x: 1, y: "will"});
items.push({x: 4, y: "happen"});
var returnobj = {};

$.each(items, function(key, value) {
  if (returnobj.hasOwnProperty([value['x']])) {
    returnobj[value['x']] = returnobj[value['x']] + 1;
  } else {
    returnobj[value['x']] = 1;
  }
});
console.log(returnobj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```